# How to make my discord bot send messages every few seconds?(discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I am trying to make my discord bot DM the same message every few seconds(and not in quick succession). So far, I've made my discord bot send a given message a certain number of times, as provided by the user. Here's my code:

```
@client.command()
async def send(ctx, member: discord.Member, amount=1, *, content=None):
for i in range(amount):
    channel = await member.create_dm()
    await channel.send(content)
```

Any help would be well appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What is the question? Do you just want it to loop?

Comment: Do you want it to loop infinitely? What kind of delay there should be between sending messages?

Answer (score 0):

One thing is that your indentation is off. You need to add an indent to whatever you put into the command.

If you want to add a delay between messages, put `await asyncio.sleep(time)` in your loop, where `time` is your delay in seconds.

So, you should have

```
@client.command()
async def send(ctx, member: discord.Member, amount=1, *, content=None):
    for i in range(amount):
        channel = await member.create_dm()
        await channel.send(content)
        await asyncio.sleep(time)
```